# How to maintain app wide data in knockoutjs+requirejs

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs, oracle-jet

In my project, I need to maintain a common data object for all the modules in the application.

This is where I store all the REST API's and the **app wide data**. (Something like store in react redux)

**dataService.js**

```
define(['jquery', 'app'], function($, app) {


    var url = app.serviceURL;

    function loginUser(data) {
        data.type = "login";
        return $.ajax({
            url: url + '/authentication.php',
            data: data,
            method: "POST"
        });
    };

    function logoutUser(data) {
        data.type = "logout";
        return $.ajax({
            url: url + '/authentication.php',
            data: data,
            method: "POST"
        });
    };

    return {
        actions: {
            loginUser: loginUser,
            logoutUser: logoutUser
        },
        user: {
            isLoggedIn: ''
        }
    }
});
```

I am requiring `dataService.js` file in `ViewModel` files to call `login` and `logout` services.

```
dataService.actions.loginUser(data)
                .then(function(data) {
                    dataService.user.isLoggedIn = true; // I changed the app wide data here                    
    }
                });
```

My problem is, when I requiring the `dataService` in some other ViewModel, the value of `dataService.user.isLoggedIn` is set as default value. How can I preserve this as an app wide data?

Comment: I'm not really sure but it looks to me you are creating a new instance every time you call dataService, where you create your initial 'App', store it in a global reference variable so you can call that.

Answer (score -1):

It may be instantiating a new object for each module. You can create a global variable by doing:

```
document.dataService = new dataService();
```

Try using the above method. This might solve your problem.